# How to append a string in shell with awk and cURL

Tags: shell, curl, awk

I am trying to update an awk command that is being used to parse through /proc/net/ip_conntrack and output a variable string into a file that is used to show a table of Active sessions on a website.  The current command is this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "var curr_connections=["} { gsub(/(src|dst|sport|dport)=/, ""); printf "['\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'','\''%s'\''],",$1,$1 == "tcp" ? $5 : $4,$1 == "tcp" ? $7 : $6,$1 == "tcp" ? $6 : $5,$1 == "tcp" ? $8 : $7; } END { print "[null]]"}' /proc/net/ip_conntrack
```

This gives me this sample output for each line in ip_conntrack:

```
'74.125.225.145','443','http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=74.125.225.145'
```

What I would like to do is add a cURL command in there to append the IP address country of origin for the destination IP.  If I just run the following at the command line:

```
curl "http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

I sort of get the country returned in front of the command prompt.  My problem is, any way I try to add the cURL command into the awk command it just gives me the following output:

```
'tcp','192.168.2.101','55661','74.125.225.145','443','http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=74.125.225.145'
```

The modified awk command I used to get this was:

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "var curr_connections=["} { gsub(/(src|dst|sport|dport)=/, ""); printf "['\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'','\''%s'\'','\''%s'\''],",$1,$1 == "tcp" ? $5 : $4,$1 == "tcp" ? $7 : $6,$1 == "tcp" ? $6 : $5,$1 == "tcp" ? $8 : $7, $1 == "tcp" ? curl "http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip="$6 : curl "http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip="$5; } END { print "[null]]"}' /proc/net/ip_conntrack
```

I have looked through quite a few of the topics through this site and have not managed to find anything that I could incorporate to make this work.  I know the way I am trying to use the cURL is not correct but I have been unable to find the proper way to inject it here to make it do what I want.

Thank you in advance for any and all help provided.

Comment: stop trying to think of this as a one-liner. reformatting this into structured code will make it easier to think about your problem (IHMO ;-) ). What's not clear to me from your description is do you want to build up a curl command and save it as part of the output OR do you want build up a curl cmd AND THEN execute it, printing the output of the cmd into your output. Either is possible. look at awk `getline` examples for one way to execute a cmd and capture the output into a variable. Good luck!

Comment: To answer your question, I am trying to build the curl command based off of the source IP that is on that particular line in ip_conntrack and execute it immediately.  I am finding out though that this is not possible the way I was trying to do it.  As you mentioned my best bet may be to create a segment of code that loops through and builds the string then outputs it to the file.  I was hoping it could be done in one fail swoop by just changing a bit of what I already had to work with.

Answer (score 1):

To get the output of the `curl` command from within the `awk` script you should use getline into a variable from a pipe http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe . For example:

```
awk `{ 
    cmd="curl http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip="$6
    cmd | getline res
    print "The result of \""cmd"\" is: \""res"\""
}` /proc/net/ip_conntrack
```